# How to unit test a private list/how to cast an object to a list

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing, object, casting

```
public class Class1
{ 
    private List<string> list;
    public Class1()
    { 
        list = new List<string>();
    }
    private addSomethingToList(string something)
    {
         // add something to the list
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class DoSomethingToListTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSomethingToList_Something()
    {
        string string1 = "something";
        PrivateObject prob = new PrivateObject(new Class1());
        object[] arg = { string1 };
        prob.Invoke("addSomethingToList", string1);
        List<string> expected = new List<string>();
        expected.Add("something");
        object actual = prob.GetField("list");
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

this gives me

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'object' to System.Collections.ICollection'

Argument 2 being actual

and

> The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert.AreEqual(System.Collections.ICollection, System.Collections.ICollection)' has some invalid arguments

The problem is that it is evaluating expected as a List and actual as an object.

Is there a way to make it so actual is a list?

I have tried

```
List<string/object> actual = prob.GetField("list");
```

But that gives me the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I can probably make a public method for getting the list, but I'd rather know about how to do it another way.

Comment: And you do all this because you want to test private functions?

Comment: @Magnus Yes, I don't understand peoples dislike of testing private functions.

Comment: An alternative is to set them as internal and make internal methods visible to the test project.

Comment: yeah. I've decided to make the public method, as getting the list could be useful later anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can new up a single item list populated with actual

```
var actualList = new List<string>() { actual };
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actualList );
```

Comment: another error which I don't understand - The best overloaded Add method System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Comment: I changed it to new List<object> and it works. HOWEVER when running the test I'm getting.Result Message: CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.) which is weird, as they are exactly the same.

Comment: You can override the equality comparer which is the third argument in the CollectionAssert.AreEqual

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: Create a class that implements IComparer, then just new it up in the 3rd parameter eg new StringComparer() etc.